# "must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support"

Tags: support, tags, meta, required-tags

I just tried to post a question to Meta and received:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be
>   submitted because:
>
> - must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support

Why are these tags required? What are the proper usages for each one? I wasn't able to find any documentation about these tags? Should this be in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: Go here to vote to add 'Retag-Request' as one of the mandatories: [Retag-request as one of the mandatory tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15699/retag-request-as-one-of-the-mandatory-tags)

Comment: @Lance Roberts: I followed your link but I don't know what I'm supposed to do, I can not submit a question.

Comment: @Marco, All you can really do is upvote the question that the lihk takes you to.  As it gets more upvotes, it gets more attention from the team.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These required tags help keep meta organized and on topic:

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
Indicates a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
Indicates a proposal for a new feature on the site, or requests a change to an existing feature.

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
This tag indicates that the question may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and is often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion.

[support](/questions/tagged/support)
Indicates a request for assistance with one of the site's features.

Comment: support: ...or requesting a janitorial task, such as a mass-retag.

Comment: Thanks. So from your answer I would assume that this question should be `support` not `discussion`, am I correct? Also, are these tags described somewhere and I just missed them?

Comment: @Josh: Yes, this is more of a support question. These tags really should be in the FAQ, I suppose.